# split function comma separator SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, split

I would like to split the function like two separate columns with the given input string.

If I execute this function, I am getting list of rows values like

```
select * 
from dbo.Split ('sunday,9,monday,8,tuesday,9, wednesday 8, thursday 8,friday,9, saturday,8')
```

Output like row values

```
sunday 
9
monday
8
tuesday
9
wednesday
8 
thursday
8 
friday
9
saturday 
8
```

My split function is:

```
create  function dbo.Split
(
    @String varchar(max)
)
returns @SplittedValues table
(
    Id varchar(50)  
)
as
begin
    declare @SplitLength int, @Delimiter varchar(5)

    set @Delimiter = ','

    while len(@String) > 0
    begin 
        select @SplitLength = (case charindex(@Delimiter,@String) when 0 then
            len(@String) else charindex(@Delimiter,@String) -1 end)

        insert into @SplittedValues
        select substring(@String,1,@SplitLength) 

        select @String = (case (len(@String) - @SplitLength) when 0 then  ''
            else right(@String, len(@String) - @SplitLength - 1) end)
    end 
return  
end
```

But I need output like two columns days(list of days first parameter), hours,

```
+-----------+-------+
|   Days    | Hours |
+-----------+-------+
| Sunday    |    9  |
| Monday    |    8  |
| Tuesday   |    9  |
| Wednesday |    8  |
| Thursday  |    8  |
| Friday    |    9  |
| saturday  |    8  |
+-----------+-------+
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Check here for various methods to convert `CSV` to `rows` with performance comparison

Comment: @Fireblade check where ? I don't see a link

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - oops missed to add the link http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1):

@user3442289  You can use below code as well. I have just altered few statements in your code.

```
create  function dbo.Split2
(
    @String varchar(max)
)
returns @SplittedValues table
(
    Id varchar(50)  ,
    Id1 int
)

begin
    declare @SplitLength int, @Delimiter varchar(5)

    set @Delimiter = ','

    while len(@String) > 0
    begin 
        select @SplitLength = (case charindex(@Delimiter,@String) when 0 then
            len(@String) else charindex(@Delimiter,@String)  end)

        insert into @SplittedValues
        select substring(@String,1,@SplitLength-1) ,SUBSTRING(@string,@SplitLength+1,1)

                select @String = (case (len(@String) - @SplitLength) when 0 then  ''
            else right(@String, len(@String) - @SplitLength-1) end)

            if @string<>'' 
            begin
            set @string=(select substring(@string,2,len(@string)))
            end

    end 
    return
end
```

Comment: hey, that's a nicer tactic than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

there might be prettier ways to do it.

```
create  function dbo.TwoColumnSplit
(
    @String varchar(max)
)
returns @returnTable table
(
    LeftId varchar(50)
    , RightId varchar(50)  
)
as
begin

declare @numCols int = 2
declare @itr int = 0
declare @SplittedValues table
(
    rowID int,
    colID int,
    Id varchar(50)  

)
    declare @SplitLength int, @Delimiter varchar(5)

    set @Delimiter = ','

    while len(@String) > 0
    begin 
        select @SplitLength = (case charindex(@Delimiter,@String) when 0 then
            len(@String) else charindex(@Delimiter,@String) -1 end)

        insert into @SplittedValues(rowID, colID, Id)
        select @itr / @numCols, @itr % @numCols, substring(@String,1,@SplitLength) 

        select @String = (case (len(@String) - @SplitLength) when 0 then  ''
            else right(@String, len(@String) - @SplitLength - 1) end)

        set @itr = @itr + 1
    end 

insert into @returnTable(LeftId, RightId)
select l.id as LeftId, r.id as RightId
from
(select rowid, id from @SplittedValues where colid = 0) l
join
(select rowid, id from @SplittedValues where colid = 1) r
on l.rowid = r.rowID

return
END

go

select * from  [dbo].[TwoColumnSplit]('sunday,9,monday,8,tuesday,9, wednesday, 8, thursday, 8,friday,9, saturday,8')
```

Comment: I have another scenario , need to split as 4 columns, can you help the final join statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471301/split-function-comma-separator-four-columns-sql-server